# pausing execution javascript in code not in google chrome debugger

Tags: debugging, google-chrome

I am writing a Google Chrome extension.  One of my content scripts has a little bug that I can't find and the Google Chrome debugger appears to be useless for this purpose.  The code stops on an Uncaught typeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null.  I can see this by opening the debugger and viewing the console after the code fails.  But my content script does not appear in the list of scripts shown in the debugger at this point.  There are a lot of scripts shown there, including a big block of scripts in light blue.  But none named "profile.js" which is my content script.

I tried "location.reload(); but it simply returns "undefined."  I'd love to step thru this code and find the problem but I can't figure out how to do it.  I've set alerts to try to track the problem but once I click on the alert, the script continues with no opportunity to invoke the debugger.  Based on the result of the alert experiment, it appears the code is failing at the very end.  I presume the code is finished by the time the error is caught and the script is no longer available to the debugger.

I tried adding this line to the script: "debugger;" to try and force the debugger to open but there is no change whatever to the execution of the code.  It fails as usual and as usual I can open the debugger, find the console message and the big list of scripts that does not include mine.

How can I pause execution of the code using a line in the code itself?  I just want to stop execution of the code at the beginning, invoke the debugger, set up some breakpoints, resume execution and monitor some variables.  That seems like a pretty simple and do-able request.

Any ideas?

Comment: When the instruction `debugger;` executes, the Chrome Developer Tools already has to be open for execution to stop. You can't force it to open from a script. Also, have you tried to stop on uncaught exceptions (http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-exceptions.html#pause_on_exceptions)?